# Подписаться на получение данных через вебсокет

Tags: c#, websocket

Скачал библиотеку для работы с API одной криптобиржи. Там есть файл с примерами, из которого я и взял подписку на обновления через вебсокет. Сам код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient();
        // Streams
        var successDepth = socketClient.SubscribeToOrderBookUpdates("bnbbtc", 1000, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.Symbol);
        });
    }
```

Почему в консоль ничего не выходит? И как сделать так, чтоб информация приходила в реальном времени без остановки(не разово, как сейчас)?

Comment: А что вы хотели? Метод отработал и все. Надо в цикле считывать данные.

Comment: Понял. А консоль пустая потому, что на момент запроса не передается информация?

Comment: Нужно читать доки к этой библиотеке чтоб ответить.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Добавил цикл - все работает)

Comment: Да, и Console.ReadLIne() тоже работает) Спасибо.